# Start exe from Windows Metro App

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

I need to create a `Windows Metro App(Windows Tile)`. From the `Metro App`, i have to start a `.exe` file.

Also can i retrieve `drive/folder` data from metro app

But i can't start the `.exe`.

Comment: did you get anny errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, it is a security risk so it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Refering this Page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

You can register a URI pluggable protocol of the .exe file, and by this protocol you can run the exe file by the source below:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"protocolName:///"));
```